# Não consigo receber mensagens para o meu App em modo release

Tags: c#, android, xamarin

Em debug, pegava o token e adiconava no meu sender e enviava PN. Deletei, recompilei em release mode e agora não consigo enviar PN(Push Notification). Veja o código do meu sender:

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            Task t = new Task(async () =>
            {
                await SenderMessage();
            });
            t.Start();
        }

        public static async Task<IFCMResponse> SenderMessage()
        {
            FCMClient client = new FCMClient("AAAA0myCZjE:APA91bETPO0K3EtgBhHz_gMXDtBTiQrCsFaOW8wmFxbk5XKrQ57KvYhxTRIW9ZQR_mxNU8ThWe0d0A40JzG-GGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGG/
            var message = new Message()
            {
                To = "Meu_Token_Gerado_Em_Debug_Anteriormente", //topic example /topics/all
                Notification = new AndroidNotification()
                {
                    Body = "Solicitação de Novo Desconto",
                    Title = "Desconto",
                }
            };
            //CrossBadge.Current.SetBadge(1, "Teste");
            var result = await client.SendMessageAsync(message);
            return result;
        }
    }
```

Existe alguma forma de fixar um token para o App? Tentei criar um **topics** e enviar a PN pelo topics, mas dá erro. Esse é o código para criar o topics

E esse é o erro:

**Not Registered**

**EDIT1**

Peço desculpas a todos, que misturei as coisas. Essa mensagem não é do recebimento de PN, mas sim da tentativa de criar um ***topics*** para receber PN, mas são coisas distintas. Vou remover essa parte. Estava sendo ajudado pelo Perozzo e mesmo assim, não influiu em nada, pois ele entendeu ao longo da nossa conversa o meu problema, apesar dele se referir à mensagem postada por mim. Erro meu, postei no "embalo" de querer resolver.

Comment: A mensagem de erro diz exatamente o que deve fazer, chamar o método FirebaseApp.InitializeApp(Context) antes de enviar o Push Notification.

Comment: O problema que eu não tenho o FirebaseApp, não sei de que classe pertence. Estou exatamente procurando isso.

Comment: Dei uma procurada aqui. Vi que se deletar a pasta obj e bin do seu projeto e depois der um rebuild novamente, irá funcionar. Delete as pastas com o visual studio fechado. Abra o projeto e de rebuild.

Comment: @Perozzo, o arquivo google-services.json deveria fazer as coisas automaticamente. Não deveria adicionar nenhum,a linha a mais, conforme a mensagem.

Comment: Editei o título que estava errado. É receber e não enviar.

Comment: Conforme pesquisei, isso é um bug. Tentou fazer isso que falei?

Comment: Vamos [continuar esta discussão no chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/67896/discussion-between-perozzo-and-pnet).